# Testing controller actions in Rails when using auth0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, auth0

I'm building a new rails app, and decided to try Auth0 instead of Devise or Sorcery, but I'm having trouble testing authenticated requests. Devise and Sorcery have a `log_in(user)` method for tests to make subsequent requests authenticated, but I can't find anything similar for Auth0 apps which would set a user's auth in the session. Rails also no longer allows you to manually set session variables from an integration test. Has anyone found a good way to do this?

To clarify, here's what I do in the `callback` url after a normal Auth0 log in

```rb
   # find user based on auto0 params
   session[:user_id] = user.id
```

Comment: The way that Devise does testing is that it uses Warden which is middleware instead of writing directly to the session. By simply setting `Warden.test_mode!` you can mock out the response from the authentication layer. I would probally just use Warden (yes it can be used on its own) as the middleware strategy is a good solution to the problem.

Comment: See https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/Overview